# Is it possible to loop through an API, print separate results, and then combine them into a single variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, loops, reddit

I’m trying to read the sentiment of multiple Reddit posts. I’ve got the idea to work using 6 API calls but I think we can refactor it to 2 calls.

The wall I’m hitting - is it possible to loop through multiple APIs (one loop for each Reddit post we’re scrapping), print the results, and then add them into a single variable?

The last part is where I’m stuck. After looping through the API, I get separate outputs for each loop and I don’t know how to add them into a single variable…

Here’s a simple version of what the code looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


function App() {

    const [testRedditComments, setTestRedditComments] = useState([]);

    const URLs = [
        'https://www.reddit.com/r/SEO/comments/tepprk/is_ahrefs_worth_it/',
        'https://www.reddit.com/r/juststart/comments/jvs0d1/is_ahrefs_worth_it_with_these_features/',
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        URLs.forEach((URL) => {
            fetch(URL + '.json').then((res) => {
                res.json().then((data) => {
                    if (data != null) setTestRedditComments(data[1].data.children);
                });
            });
        });
    }, []);

    
    //This below finds the reddit comments and puts them into an array
    const testCommentsArr = testRedditComments.map(
        (comments) => comments.data.body
    );

    //This below takes the reddit comments and terns them into a string.
    const testCommentsArrToString = testCommentsArr.join(' ');


    console.log(testCommentsArrToString);
```

I've tried multiple approaches to adding the strings together but I've sunk a bunch of time. Anyone know how this works. Or is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

Thanks for your time and if you need any clarification let me know.

-Josh

Comment: I think you can use `Promise.all` for your API calls and that returns the array of responses in the same order as to how your APIs are placed. You can use them for your functionality.

Comment: @mchowdam this didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const URLs = [
  "https://www.reddit.com/r/SEO/comments/tepprk/is_ahrefs_worth_it/",
  "https://www.reddit.com/r/juststart/comments/jvs0d1/is_ahrefs_worth_it_with_these_features/",
];
Promise.all(
  URLs.map(async (url) => {
    const resp = await fetch(url + ".json");
    return resp.json();
  })
).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

I have used `Promise.all` and got the response and attached a react sandbox with the same.

[image: Edit rough-rgb-6nk9gz]

Based on your requirements, you can use state value or you can prepare your api response before setting it to state.

Comment: This Worked. Really appreciate it. This opened a whole new door that I thought I looked through. Thank you!